# If number are equal and even pop an alert

Tags: javascript

I have few problems with JavaScript. I don't know why it's not working. I've searched the internet but didn't find anything.

I need to popup an alert if both number are equal to popup number (if they are equal) if not, an alert with message (Please insert numbers). But I can't make it work.

```javascript
function even(){
    var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("n").value);
    var m = parseInt(document.getElementById("m").value);
    var s = 0 ;
    var i;

    if (n < m) {
        i = n;
        while (i <= m){
            if(i % 2 === 0) 
                s += i;
            i++;
        }
        alert(s);
    }
    else if (n > m) {
        i = m;
        while (i <= n) {
            if (i % 2 === 0) 
                s += i;
            i++;
        }
        alert(s);
    }
    else if (n = m) {
        i = m;
        i = n;
        while(i % 2 == 0) 
            s == i;
    }
     alert(s);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="n" > </br><br>
<input type="text" id="m" > </br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="even()">Sum Even Numbers</button>
```

Comment: In your else you need a double equals `} else if (n == m)`

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What are the values of `n` and `m` when you log them or set a breakpoint? What do you think is happening when you write `if (n = m)`?

Comment: `(n === m)` is probably what you're wanting `(n = m)` is assignment not comparison.

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Answer (score 0):

```
function even(){
var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("n").value);
var m = parseInt(document.getElementById("m").value);

  if(n % 2 == 0 && m % 2 == 0){
    alert(n + m);
  }
}
```

This is way simpler and does work only if n & m are even numbers. Thanks to `n % 2 == 0` and `m % 2 == 0` which divide the numbers by to and check if the remainder is equal to 0.

**EDIT**

But reading your question again I'm not sure it is you want to achieve. You might want to be more precise.

Comment: I need to show only 1 numbers . Ex: if i input in those texboxes  2 and 2 , i want to get an popup with 2 or  4 and 4  popup with 4 . not sum, if i enter 3 and 3 (alert with 0 ) Because none are even number .                                          Edit: i modify your  `alert(n=m);` and it work . ty

Comment: If this answer is correct you should close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you have above, I assume goal is to sum the even numbers between `n` and `m`. Something like this? Perhaps,

```
function even() {

    var n = parseInt(document.getElementById("n").value);
    var m = parseInt(document.getElementById("m").value);
    var s = 0;

    var start = Math.min(n, m);
    var end = Math.max(n, m);
    for (var i = start; i <= end; ++i) {
        if (i % 2 === 0) { 
            s += i;
        }
    }

    alert(s);

}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Angryr/L6dyjea6/)

**Notes**

- `while(i%2 == 0) s == i;` should probably be `while(i % 2 == 0) { s = i; }`
- `}else if(n=m) {` should probably be `} else if (n === m) {`
- I used `Math.min()` and `Math.max()` since it seemed like the first two sections of your if-statement did the same thing but with `n` and `m` swapped.

Comment: Yes , That is what i want . But you make it way to simple . i will use yours . Ty for notes too

Comment: Please accept the answer if this is indeed correct.